# Calculate Shipping Cost In Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, checkout

Using the store tags for displaying the various items and values for the orders, how would I be able to calculate the shipping cost according to the user's delivery/billing address entered during the checkout process? As the user is checking out, I need to update a sidebar with all the costs, including the shipping cost for which I am using the store tags.

Comment: I havn't really tried anything so far though, just want to know how to calculate these and if store perhaps have some built-in feature one can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module out there that will integrate with the USPS API and calculate that shipping for you.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/expresso-store-usps-shipping

Comment: This looks good, is there perhaps one using the South African Postal Service? I see this one is using the United States postal service. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but depending on the South African Postal Service API you could use this one as a reference to connect to the South african postal service. I also know there is a fedex plugin as well that might help?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/expresso-store-fedex-shipping